# POST file upload causes HTTP 400 error response

Tags: python, file, http, upload, python-requests

I am trying to upload a file using POST requests in Python (requests library).
I get `HTTP 400 error` as a response. I think it is because my POST request is not in the format it should be. Any ideas how to convert POST request 1 into 2?

Code:

```
files = {"file": ("test-file.txt", open("c:/users/johndoe/desktop/test-file.txt", "rb"), "text/plain")}
response = webdriver.request("POST", "https://something.com/attachments", files = files)
```

**What I currently have (1):**

```
--d9bd23df892242a489b0f638d62502a6
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="test-file.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

This is a test file.

Regards,

John Doe
--d9bd23df892242a489b0f638d62502a6--
```

**What I should have (2):**

```
-----------------------------26789175756830
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileName"

test-file.txt
-----------------------------26789175756830
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileSize"

45
-----------------------------26789175756830
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="description"

undefined
-----------------------------26789175756830
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="test-file.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

This is a test file.

Regards,

John Doe
-----------------------------26789175756830--
```

**What I think I need to add (3):**

```
-----------------------------26789175756830
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileName"

test-file.txt
-----------------------------26789175756830
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileSize"

45
-----------------------------26789175756830
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="description"

undefined
-----------------------------26789175756830
```

Comment: What makes you think you need to specify "fileName", "fileSize", and "description" fields? `Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="test-file.txt"` is exactly what browsers generate for an `<input>` of type file in a multipart encoded form.

Comment: Because I have compared my request with requests from the website and the only difference I found was this part.

Comment: I think that the server expects this format. Do you think this could be the case?

Comment: Sure, it could be using this format. I was just wondering where you got the format from. I thought maybe the site you were using had some documentation explaining it.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot No unfortunately not, but any idea how I can add this part to my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to explicitly specify the fields `fileName`, `fileSize`, and `description`, since requests won't generate them for you automatically:

```
import os
import requests

filepath = 'foo'
files = {'file': open(filepath, 'rb')}
data = {
    'fileName': filepath,
    'fileSize': os.path.getsize(filepath),
    'description': 'undefined'
}

response = requests.post('http://www.example.com/', data=data, files=files);
```

This generates a request like:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: www.example.com
User-Agent: python-requests/2.13.0
Content-Length: 439
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=75a7213b6b4f493fabe26feeafb8551c
Http.Entity.Parser.Multipart.Tempdir: /tmp/pZjDE

--75a7213b6b4f493fabe26feeafb8551c
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="description"

undefined
--75a7213b6b4f493fabe26feeafb8551c
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileSize"

16
--75a7213b6b4f493fabe26feeafb8551c
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileName"

foo
--75a7213b6b4f493fabe26feeafb8551c
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="foo"

contents of foo

--75a7213b6b4f493fabe26feeafb8551c--
```